# Golang ShouldBindJSON giving errors as unexpected EOF and i/o timeout

Tags: go, http-post, go-gin

With Golang ShouldBindJSON(&dto) sometimes I'm getting three kings of errors. I have a dto struct as given below

```
type RequestDto struct {
    Customers []CustomerDto `json:"customers" binding:"required,max=100,dive"`
}

type CustomerDto struct {
    Name       string    `json:"name" binding:"required"`
    Roles map[string]any `json:"roles"`
}
```

One of the error that I'm getting is `customer.RequestDto.Customers: []customer.CustomerDto: customer.CustomerDto.Roles: unexpected EOF`

Another one is `customer.RequestDto.Customers: []customer.CustomerDto: customer.CustomerDto.Roles: read tcp 10.216.24.153:8000->127.0.0.6:58167: i/o timeout`

And last one is just `EOF`

What might be the reason for it? How to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: It's possible `any` is causing the issue. You need to give more details on the json string, the code where shouldbindjson is used and any relevant debugging details. Just this is not enough to debug the issue. It can also be related to api request having issues.

Comment: 1. I think u should check the incoming JSON data that you're trying to parse. Ensure that it matches the structure defined in your DTO, and all required fields are present.

2. read tcp ... i/o timeout: This error suggests that there might be a network issue causing a timeout while reading the JSON data.